# UIMenuController setTargetRect detail

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller

I m not able to understand what should I pass in "setTargetRect" & inView to display UIMenuController. Currently I want to show this menu on button click. This view is not getting displayed in my current view.

This is what I have done to set the target rect.
[menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(myButton.bounds.origin.x, myButton.bounds.origin.y, 0.0f, 0.0f) inView:myView];

What m I missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please show the menu using

you should give height and width in Rect :

```
CGRectMake(myButton.bounds.origin.x, myButton.bounds.origin.y, 100.0f, 100.0f)


[menuController setMenuVisible: YES animated: YES];
```